# Laravel broken translator (affects validation messages)

Tags: laravel, validation, localization

I have a problem with validation in Laravel. It used to work properly but now it does not. I do not know when the problem started.

The problem appears using the Validator class or a custom request file.

For example:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'username' => 'required',
]);
```

If `username` is missing will produce an error bag containing the following error text:

```
validation.required
```

which is useless as far as validation feedback goes. If another field does not satisfy the minimum length, the error bag will contain:

```
validation.required
validation.min
```

Instead it should use the descriptions in the `lang/en/validation.php` file: `'The :attribute field is required.'` i.e. `'The username field is required.'`

It seems like the lang file is completely ignored. I checked it, and it contains a valid array. I don't know how to troubleshoot this. Can you please help?

I print out the errors as follows:

```
@if ($errors->any())
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
      @foreach ($errors->all() as $message)
        <li>{{ $message }}</li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>
@endif
```

Example of message bag as seen from the debugger: [image: Example of message bag as seen from the debugger]

UPDATE: I found the original cause of the problem.

```
# vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Translation/Translator.php 
public function get( ..
```

this function fails to retrieve the translated line.
Because the load() function fails to load the contents of lang/en/validation.php
Because it's looking for it in the wrong path (/resources/lang/).
Because there exists a /resource/lang folder, which was put there by a third party package (outdated, that was the path in laravel 8).

Comment: how are you getting the error bag ?

Comment: `validation.required` is the correct key, but when you try to display the errors, it should say `The username field is required`. You didn't include any code to show how you're displaying it, so we can't really help much beyond that. For example, after actually performing the validation (i.e. `if($validator->passes())`), in any `.blade.php` file, if you do `$errors->first('username')`, what does it say?

Comment: N69S in debugging I can see the messages that will be printed out in the view

Comment: which laravel version you are using ?

Comment: @TimLewis it says "validation.required", as I already explained

Comment: @Zia version 9.45.1

Comment: FYI I didn't downvote you (and I'm not too sure why you were downvoted), but leaving sarcastic comments is probably a good way to get more downvotes... As for your issue, I'll try to recreate it. This is not how validation works in my experience, so there must be something going on. Did you omit your actual validation call `if($validation->passes())` (or `$validation->fails()`, etc.))?

Comment: @TimLewis thank you. Having a large number of fields, I prefer using custom request files (in app/Http/Requests/), and they do not require to call the methods you mentioned. But I tried to troubleshoot the issue by reverting back to the `$validator = Validator::make()` method, and then of course I had an `if ( $validator->fails() ) { ... }`

Comment: @TimLewis the results the same. My `lang/en/validation.php` file is customized. I tried to remove all customization but it didn't help.

Comment: Yeah, for sure. Custom requests for validation is always a better idea than a manual validator. I get trying to do this for debugging purposes, but I'm not able to recreate this... I added `$validator = Validator::make($request->input(), ['name' => 'required'])`, then `if($validator->fails()) { return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator); }`, and doing `@foreach($errors as $error)` (or `$errors->all()`), then `{{ $error }}`, it displays `The Name field is required'`... Same with `$errors->first('name')`. I don't have access to a Laravel 9 project, but this is Laravel 8.

Comment: ok, thanks for trying. So the problem is not with my controller, not with the custom request (the issue affects all of them), not with the lang file.  Must be something lower level..

Comment: thanks again. The issue occurs with both the custom requests and the validator instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in fact with the translation subsystem.

It's been caused by a third party plugin which created a /resources/lang folder. This was the lang folder location in Laravel 8, and it still takes precedence over the new location /lang. But the necessary files were not there and the translation failed without raising any exception (!!!).

Removing the /resources/lang folder resolved my issue.